# What are your suggestions for an ideal Vim configuration for Perl development?

Tags: perl, vim, configuration

There are a lot of threads pertaining to how to configure [Vim/GVim](http://www.vim.org/) for Perl development [on PerlMonks.org](http://www.google.com/search?q=vimrc+site%3Aperlmonks.org). My purpose in posting this question is to try to create, as much as possible, an ideal configuration for Perl development using Vim/GVim. Please post your suggestions for `.vimrc` settings as well as useful plugins.

I will try to merge the recommendations into a set of `.vimrc` settings and to a list of recommended plugins, ftplugins and syntax files.

#### .vimrc settings

```
"Create a command :Tidy to invoke perltidy"
"By default it operates on the whole file, but you can give it a"
"range or visual range as well if you know what you're doing."
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!
    \perltidy -your -preferred -default -options <args>

vmap <tab> >gv    "make tab in v mode indent code"
vmap <s-tab> <gv

nmap <tab> I<tab><esc> "make tab in normal mode indent code"
nmap <s-tab> ^i<bs><esc>

let perl_include_pod   = 1    "include pod.vim syntax file with perl.vim"
let perl_extended_vars = 1    "highlight complex expressions such as @{[$x, $y]}"
let perl_sync_dist     = 250  "use more context for highlighting"

set nocompatible "Use Vim defaults"
set backspace=2  "Allow backspacing over everything in insert mode"

set autoindent   "Always set auto-indenting on"
set expandtab    "Insert spaces instead of tabs in insert mode. Use spaces for indents"
set tabstop=4    "Number of spaces that a <Tab> in the file counts for"
set shiftwidth=4 "Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent"

set showmatch    "When a bracket is inserted, briefly jump to the matching one"
```

#### syntax

- [vim-perl: Support for Perl 5 and Perl 6 in Vim](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl)

#### plugins

- [delimitMate provides auto-completion for quotes, parens, brackets, etc. in insert mode](http://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate). It handles apostrophes more intelligently than [closepairs.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2373) does.
- [perlhelp.vim: Interface to perldoc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1913)
- [taglist.vim: Source code browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273)

#### ftplugins

- [perldoc.vim: perldoc command from vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=209)

#### CPAN modules

- [Vim::X](https://metacpan.org/pod/Vim::X)

#### Debugging tools

I just found out about [VimDebug](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=663). I have not yet been able to install it on Windows, but looks promising from the description.

Comment: The .vimrc settings should be heavily commented. E.g., what does perl_include_pod do?

Comment: Thank you! (Dear Lord, why are we not allowed to say "Thank you!" in a comment?)

Comment: @Manni: You are welcome. I have been using the same `.vimrc` for many years and a recent bunch of vim related questions got me curious. I was too lazy to wade through everything that was posted on PerlMonks (and see what was current etc.), so I figured we could put together something here.

Comment: I think that that's a great idea. Sorry that my own contribution is that lame.

Comment: Rather than closepairs, I would recommend delimitMate or one of the various autoclose plugins. (There are about three named autoclose, I think.) The closepairs plugin can't handle a single apostrophe inside a string (i.e. `print "This isn't so hard, is it?"`), but delimitMate and others can. http://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate

Comment: The vim-perl project incorporates the contents of "perl-mauke.vim: improved perl syntax highlighting".

Answer (score 4):

From [chromatic's blog](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/10/from-novice-to-adept-cleaning-up-bad-code.html) (slightly adapted to be able to use the same mapping from all modes).

```
vmap ,pt :!perltidy<CR> 
nmap ,pt :%! perltidy<CR>
```

hit `,pt` in normal mode to clean up the whole file, or in visual mode to clean up the selection. You could also add:

```
imap ,pt <ESC>:%! perltidy<CR>
```

But using commands from input mode is not recommended.

Comment: I seem to be missing something here: How can I type ,ptv without vim running perltidy on the entire file?

Comment: Ovid's comment (#3) seems offer a much better solution.

Comment: Three hours later: turns out that the 'p' in that mapping is a really bad idea. It will bite you when vim's got something to paste.

Comment: @Manni: select a region first: with the mouse if using gvim, or with visual mode (`v` and then use motion commands).

Comment: That's not what I meant. If ',pt' runs tidy on the complete file, why would vim wait for me to type 'v' if I am in visual mode? And how long?

Comment: @Manni: I just gave it a try: if you type `,pt`, vim waits for you to type something else (e.g. <cr>) as a signal that the command is ended. Hitting `,ptv` will immediately format the region.  So I would expect that vim recognizes that there is overlap between the mappings, and waits for disambiguation before proceeding.

Comment: Try vmap ,pt <ESC>:'<,'>! perltidy<CR> instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
" Create a command :Tidy to invoke perltidy.
" By default it operates on the whole file, but you can give it a
" range or visual range as well if you know what you're doing.
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!
    \perltidy -your -preferred -default -options <args>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look also at [perl-support.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=556) (a Perl IDE for Vim/gVim).
Comes with suggestions for customizing Vim (.vimrc), gVim (.gvimrc),
ctags, perltidy, and Devel:SmallProf beside many other things.

Comment: I **hate** that one. The comments feature alone deserves a thorough 'rm -rf', IMHO.

Comment: I hate the fact that \$ is changed automatically to a "my $" declaration (same with \@ and \%). Does the author never use references or what?!

Comment: I take pieces of that one.  If it were a man, you'd say about him, "He was only good for transplants..."

Answer (score 3):

[Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) has an appendix on [Editor Configurations](http://books.google.com/books?id=yMMRnPQ7CSMC&lpg=PP1&ots=_ja9em6fLf&dq=perl%20best%20practices&pg=PA482#v=onepage&q=&f=false).  vim is the first editor listed.

Answer (score 3):

Andy Lester and others [maintain](http://use.perl.org/comments.pl?sid=42657&cid=67949) the official Perl, Perl 6 and Pod support files for Vim on Github: https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl

Comment: Note that that link is already listed in the body of the question (look under **syntax**).

Answer (score 2):

For tidying, I use the following; either `\t` to tidy the whole file, or I select a few lines in `shift+V` mode and then do `\t`

```
nnoremap <silent> \t :%!perltidy -q<Enter>
vnoremap <silent> \t :!perltidy -q<Enter>
```

Sometimes it's also useful to deparse code. As the above lines, either for the whole file or for a selection.

```
nnoremap <silent> \D :.!perl -MO=Deparse 2>/dev/null<CR>
vnoremap <silent> \D :!perl -MO=Deparse 2>/dev/null<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

.vimrc:

```
" Allow :make to run 'perl -c' on the current buffer, jumping to 
" errors as appropriate
" My copy of vimparse: http://irc.peeron.com/~zigdon/misc/vimparse.pl

set makeprg=$HOME/bin/vimparse.pl\ -c\ %\ $*

" point at wherever you keep the output of pltags.pl, allowing use of ^-]
" to jump to function definitions.

set tags+=/path/to/tags
```

Comment: What is pltags.pl? Is it better than ctags?

Comment: Could you please explain if there are any advantages to using `pltags.pl` rather than `taglist.vim` w/ `ctags`?

Comment: And vimparse.pl really works for you? Is that really the correct URL?

Comment: Yeah, I use vimparse quite a bit, and find it very useful.  Is the URL not working for you?

Comment: I've never tried using ctags for perl scripts - does it follow the modules used?

Comment: @zigdon How is `vimparse.pl` different than Vim's quickfix mode? See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html

Comment: @sinan it enables quickfix - all it does is reformat the output of perl -c so that vim parses it as compiler errors. The the usual quickfix commands work.

Comment: @zigdon OK. Got it. One final question then: Have you used `Vi::QuickFix`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of my .vimrc settings. They may not be Perl specific, but I couldn't work without them:

```
set nocompatible        " Use Vim defaults (much better!) "
set bs=2                " Allow backspacing over everything in insert mode "
set ai                  " Always set auto-indenting on "
set showmatch           " show matching brackets "

" for quick scripts, just open a new buffer and type '_perls' "
iab _perls #!/usr/bin/perl<CR><BS><CR>use strict;<CR>use warnings;<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting module I found on the weekend: [`App::EditorTools::Vim`](http://code-and-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/07/stealing-from-padre-for-vim-part-3.html). Its most interesting feature seems to be its ability to rename lexical variables. Unfortunately, my tests revealed that it doesn't seem to be ready yet for any production use, but it sure seems worth to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2.

The first one I know I picked up part of it from someone else, but I can't remember who. Sorry unknown person. Here's how I made "C^N" auto complete work with Perl. Here's my .vimrc commands.

```
" to use CTRL+N with modules for autocomplete "
set iskeyword+=:
set complete+=k~/.vim_extras/installed_modules.dat
```

Then I set up a cron to create the installed_modules.dat file. Mine is for my mandriva system. Adjust accordingly.

```
locate *.pm | grep "perl5" | sed -e "s/\/usr\/lib\/perl5\///" | sed -e "s/5.8.8\///" | sed -e "s/5.8.7\///" | sed -e "s/vendor_perl\///" | sed -e "s/site_perl\///" | sed -e "s/x86_64-linux\///" | sed -e "s/\//::/g" | sed -e "s/\.pm//" >/home/jeremy/.vim_extras/installed_modules.dat
```

The second one allows me to use gf in Perl. Gf is a shortcut to other files. just place your cursor over the file and type gf and it will open that file.

```
" To use gf with perl "
set path+=$PWD/**,
set path +=/usr/lib/perl5/*,
set path+=/CompanyCode/*,   " directory containing work code "
autocmd BufRead *.p? set include=^use
autocmd BufRead *.pl set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\(.*\\)','\\1.pm','i')
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the following abbreviations useful

```
iab perlb  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n <p>zdebug + $_ + $' + $`  line ".__LINE__.__FILE__."\n";exit;
iab perlbb print "Content-type: text/html\n\n<p>zdebug  <C-R>a  line ".__LINE__.__FILE__."\n";exit;
iab perlbd do{print "Content-type: text/html\n\n<p>zdebug  <C-R>a  line ".__LINE__."\n";exit} if $_ =~ /\w\w/i;
iab perld print "Content-type: text/html\n\n dumper";use Data::Dumper;$Data::Dumper::Pad="<br>";print Dumper <C-R>a ;exit;

iab perlf foreach $line ( keys %ENV )<CR> {<CR> }<LEFT><LEFT>
iab perle while (($k,$v) = each %ENV) { print "<br>$k = $v\n"; }
iab perli x = (i<4) ? 4 : i;
iab perlif if ($i==1)<CR>{<CR>}<CR>else<CR>{<CR>}
iab perlh $html=<<___HTML___;<CR>___HTML___<CR>
```

You can make them perl only with

```
au bufenter *.pl iab xbug print "<p>zdebug ::: $_ :: $' :: $`  line ".__LINE__."\n";exit;
```

Comment: there's no `my` anywhere there; I take it you usually write CGIs with no `use strict;`? (just curious if this is so)

Comment: Oh wow, and without CGI.pm as well. It's like a 15 year flashback.

Answer (score 0):

By far the most useful are

1. Perl filetype pluging (ftplugin) - this colour-codes various code
   elements
2. Creating a check-syntax-before-saving command "W"
   preventing you from saving bad code (you can override with the normal 'w').

Installing he plugins are a bit dicky as the version of vim (and linux) put the plugins in different places. Mine are in ~/.vim/after/

my .vimrc below.

```
set vb
set ts=2
set sw=2
set enc=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8,prc
set guifont=Monaco:h11
set guifontwide=NSimsun:h12
set pastetoggle=<F3>
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!
    \perltidy
filetype plugin on
augroup JumpCursorOnEdit
 au!
 autocmd BufReadPost *
 \ if expand("<afile>:p:h") !=? $TEMP |
 \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
 \ let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = line("'\"") |
 \ let b:doopenfold = 1 |
 \ if (foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo) > foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1)) |
 \ let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1 |
 \ let b:doopenfold = 2 |
 \ endif |
 \ exe JumpCursorOnEdit_foo |
 \ endif |
 \ endif
 " Need to postpone using "zv" until after reading the modelines.
 autocmd BufWinEnter *
 \ if exists("b:doopenfold") |
 \ exe "normal zv" |
 \ if(b:doopenfold > 1) |
 \ exe "+".1 |
 \ endif |
 \ unlet b:doopenfold |
 \ endif
augroup END
```